# Can users with read permission use an add-in that makes a REST Post?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint 2013 add-in that uses the SP REST API to add an item to a library on the host web.  I don't want to grant app users edit-level permissions to the library since the app will be in charge of adding library items, not the user.  I have already set the app's permission level in the app manifest to full-control, however the app's Post call returns an error when a user with read permissions attempts to use the app.  Is there anyway for a user with read permissions to use an app that Posts to a host library?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Add-in-only policy. In Visual Studio, open app manifest in design mode and there is a checkbox in upper left corner on the permissions tab.
Add-ins-only policy enables Add-ins to use separate access rights in given scope. It should do the job for you.

Comment: I am sure that @Y.MoumenElidrissi is wrong. And following the link you can find:  Add-in-only policy - "When the add-in-only policy is used, SharePoint checks only the permissions of the add-in principal."

Comment: One more thing. I have created couple of provider hosted Add-Ins working this way. I have never used SharePoint hosted Add-Ins.

Comment: After some research, it turns out that the add-in only policy only works for provider hosted apps

Comment: @Radas I'm not wrong **Add-in only policy** works only for Provider hosted apps and **User+add-in policy** works for SharePoint hosted apps.
**Apps that do not make OAuth authenticated calls (for example, apps that are only JavaScript running in the app web) cannot use the app-only policy**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a Rest Post action on host web with users that have read permission.
Check this link and read **User+add-in policy** : [Get an overview of add-in authorization policies types](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/add-in-authorization-policy-types-in-sharepoint#Overview)